# (R) How to see how many times event happens from two different datasets

Tags: r

Okay so here is my database

```
Game    Player    Hit   Something else
1       Trout     TRUE  1
1       Pujols    FALSE 5
1       Hunter    TRUE  6
1       Trout     TRUE  7
2       Hunter    TRUE  23
2       Pujols    FALSE 0
```

etc and it goes down to 162 games. So if I have on a different data frame

```
Player    Number of Games with at least one hit
Trout
Hunter
Pujols
```

how would I get the second column. I need a statement that will filter the player and the game because making a subset for each individual player and game would take too long. I need to count the number of times a player has gotten a hit but only for each game.
Thanks

Comment: `aggregate(Game ~ Player, df[df$Hit,], FUN = length)`

Comment: I need the number of GAMES the player had with at least one hit. I keep getting the amount of hits the player got total.

Comment: The thing is there are other collumns that will be distinct too.

Comment: @willmccormack14 Welcome to SO! Please put the additional informations from your comments into your question, i.e. edit yout question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43015243/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, the following would work with `dplyr`.  Just look at the true values of Hit, remove any duplicates (i.e. games with more than one hit), then count the number of rows per player.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Game=c(1,1,1,1,2,2),Player=c("Trout","Pujols","Hunter","Trout","Hunter","Pujols"),Hit=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))

df2 <- df %>% filter(Hit) %>% distinct(Game,Player) %>% count(Player)
```

This will give you the second data frame you mention.  Or, if it already exists (`df3`), you could merge the new data into it with `df3 <- df3 %>% left_join(df2)`.

Comment: Thats good but that counts the number of times a player got a hit. I want to count the number of GAMES where a player got at least one hit. But thanks for the response.

Comment: The `distinct()` function takes out any duplicate entries, so only counts a game once in which the player gets at least one hit.

Comment: I tried that but then it said `unknown variable to group by : Player'

Comment: Is your data in a data.frame, with variable names `Game`, `Player` and `Hit`?

Comment: would you put anything in the distinct parentheses. Wouldn't you want a distinct game number. When I left it blank it just gave me the amount of total hits.

Comment: `distinct()` without arguments just removes any duplicate rows (same game, player and hit values), so that any game for which a player gets more than one hit is only counted once.

Comment: I keep doing it but I keep getting the amount of total hits the player has gotten.

Comment: The thing is there are other collumns that will be distinct too I added it.

Comment: `distinct(Game,Player)` should do it